# Counts and divide from two different selects with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this kind of structure (Sample only)

```
ID | STATUS | DATE |
--- -------- ------
1    OPEN    31-01-2022
2    CLOSE   15-11-2021
3    CLOSE    21-10-2021
4    OPEN    11-10-2021
5    OPEN    28-09-2021
```

I would like to know the counts of close vs open records by week. So it will be count(close)/count(open) where close.week = open.week
If there are no matching values, need to return 0 of course.

I got to this query below

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'CLOSE',  DATEPART(WEEK, DATE) AS 'WEEKSA', DATEPART(YEAR, DATE) AS 'YEARA' FROM TABLE
WHERE STATUS IN ('CLOSE')
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, DATE),DATEPART(YEAR, DATE)) TMPA 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'OPEN',  DATEPART(WEEK, DATE) AS 'WEEKSB', DATEPART(YEAR, DATE) AS 'YEARB' FROM TABLE
WHERE STATUS IN ('OPEN')
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, DATE),DATEPART(YEAR, DATE)) TMPB
ON TMPA.WEEKSA = TMPB.WEEKSB AND TMPA.YEARA = TMPB.YEARB
```

My results are as below (sample only)

```
  close |   weeksa | yeara | open | weeksb | yearb |
    ------ -------- ------ ------- -------  ------
                                3   2       2021
                                1   3       2021
                                1   4       2021
        2   20      2021        2   20      2021
                                7   22      2021
                                2   23      2021
                                7   26      2021
                                7   27      2021
        2   28      2021        14  28      2021
                                2   29      2021
                                10  30
                                24  31      2021
        2   32      2021        5   32
                                4   33      2021
        1   34      2021        13  34      2021
                                6   35      2021
                                1   36      2021
        1   38      2021
                                1   39      2021
                                2   41      2021
                                4   43      2021
                                1   45      2021
        2   46      2021        25  46      2021
        1   47      2021        5   47      2021
                                4   48      2021
        1   49      2021        20  49      2021
        1   50      2021        17  50      2021
                                1   51      2021
```

How do I do the math now?
If I do another select the query fails. So I guess either syntax is bad or the whole concept is wrong.
The required result should look like this (Sample)

```
WEEK | YEAR | RATIO |
----- ------ -------
2       2021    0
3       2021    0
4       2021    0
5       2021    0.93
20      2021    0.1
22      2021    0
23      2021    0
26      2021    0
1       2022    0.75
2       2022    0.23
4       2022    0.07
```

Cheers!

Comment: Your desired output includes the `Year` column while your query ignores `Year`. Not sure what is the logic.

Comment: Added the year part @Serg. It got cut out in the copy&paste

Answer (score 1):

I have added some test data to check the logic, adding the same in the code.

```
;with cte as(
select 1 ID,    'OPEN'   as STATUS, cast('2021 -01-31' as DATE) DATE
union select 10 ID,    'CLOSE'   as STATUS, cast('2021 -01-31' as DATE) DATE
union select 11 ID,    'CLOSE'   as STATUS, cast('2021 -01-31' as DATE) DATE
union select 12 ID,    'CLOSE'   as STATUS, cast('2021 -01-31' as DATE) DATE
union select 22 ID,    'CLOSE'   as STATUS, cast('2021 -01-31' as DATE) DATE
union select 32 ID,    'CLOSE'   as STATUS, cast('2021 -01-31' as DATE) DATE
union select 2,'CLOSE',cast('2021-11-28'  as DATE) 
union select 3,'CLOSE',cast('2021-10-21'  as DATE) 
union select 8,'CLOSE',cast('2021-10-21'  as DATE) 
union select 9,'CLOSE',cast('2021-10-21'  as DATE) 
union select 4,'OPEN', cast('2021-10-11'  as DATE) 
union select 5,'CLOSE', cast('2021-09-28'  as DATE) 
union select 6,'OPEN', cast('2021-09-27'  as DATE) 
union select 7,'CLOSE', cast('2021-09-26'  as DATE) )
, cte2 as (
select DATEPART(WEEK,date) as week_number,* from cte)
,cte3 as(
select week_number,year(date) yr,count(case when status = 'open' then 1 end)open_count,count(case when status <> 'open' then 1 end) close_count from cte2 group by week_number,year(date))
select week_number as week,yr as year,
cast(case when open_count = 0 then 1.0 else open_count end /
case when close_count = 0 then 1.0 else     close_count end as numeric(3,2)) as ratio
from cte3
```

Comment: looks great. I'll have to analyse it as the syntax is not 100% clear to me.
Cheers!

BTW, if I need to use the IN clause? Should I just change the '=' sign to be 'IN'?

Comment: I managed to run on SQL server and I get the results.
Is there a way I can create a view from this?

Comment: you need to pass the values as list -> `in ('a','b','c')`

Comment: just use `create view <view name> as` in the begining

Comment: Thank you Moulithearan M.
That is a cool script and I have learned a lot from it.